# Properties of referenced class not showing during internal assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have below `ItemCountAmount.cs` class.

```
public class ItemCountAmount
{
     public int Count { get; set; }
     public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and I am referencing it in one more class `ChartData.cs` as below:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public ChartData()
    {
        Purchase = Stocks = Sales = new ItemCountAmount();
    }
    public string period { get; set; }
    public ItemCountAmount Purchase { get; set; }
    public ItemCountAmount Stocks { get; set; }
    public ItemCountAmount Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to assign the values for the `ChartData` properties, it isn't recognizing or available. Compile time exception will occur in VS.

```
var model = new ChartData
{
    period = yearMonth,
    Purchase.Count = await purchase.CountAsync(x => x.order_date.Month == mnth && x.order_date.Year == yr),

}
```

But `Purchase.Count` or `Purchase.Amount` isn't identified here where in if I try it as

```
var model=new ChartData();
model.Purchase.Count = .....;
model.Purchase.Amount = .....;
.......
```

it works fine, I mean, property `Count` and `Amount` is identified. I am still not getting why the first method is not able to identify the properties from `ItemCountAmount.cs` class which is referenced in `ChartData`. Any specific reasons for this?

Comment: try `var model = new ChartData()
{
    period = yearMonth,
    Purchase.Count = await purchase.CountAsync(x => x.order_date.Month == mnth && x.order_date.Year == yr),

}`. Notice the missing `()`

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @KhanhTO i think we can initialize that way as well, it's legal

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It isn't identifying the property itself... Like AutoComplete thing in `VS`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it should have you tried restarting VS ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad.. Yes I've tried restarting too.. But it still did not.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the C# object initialiser supports that syntax, however, you can just do this. I am not sure whether this would result in two constructions and assignemnts to `Purchase` though, you could break point that yourself and see.

```
var model = new ChartData 
               {
                 Purchase = new ItemCountAmount 
                               { 
                                 count = await purchase.CountAsync(x => x.order_date.Month == mnth && x.order_date.Year == yr) 
                               }
               }
```

Comment: I have separate query for `Amount`. So do I need to initialize it again for that like `new ItemCountAmount`?

Comment: Yup, although you might want to just use your second method anyway if the way shown here causes two constructions (which I'm pretty certain it will) as it would be more efficient, so `model.Purchase.Count = .....;` is probably better here.

Comment: Oh.. Alright.. Thanks much @starlight.. Will it make any difference with respect to performance, memory when 2nd method is used instead of first one?

Comment: Not unless you are creating a serious amount of these objects in a loop or something, I can confirm that it will construct `ItemCountAmount` twice if you use the first method though, so I don't think there's any reason to use it :P

Comment: the original code OP showed should also work, there is nothing wrong in that, exception the initilization of the ChartData properties, as same instance is assigned to three properties

Comment: That is not correct, see this if you want confirmation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YvhazT